# Display image using DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

Please, I am short before going mad, what could possibly cause my problem:

I am trying to display an image according to the value of my variable `ErrorDescription.Severity` using DataTriggers. I successfully display the variable as text next to the image. However, no image is shown.

**Where is my mistake?**

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding Results}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            // works, displays "Error", "Warning" or "Info"
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}"></DataGridTextColumn>

            // does not work, should display an image according to "Error", "Warning" or "Info"
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Results, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}" Value="Warning">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/warning.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger >
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}" Value="Notice">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/info.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger >
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}" Value="Error">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/error.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

More info: 
`Results` is an ObservableCollection of `Result`, `Result` does not implement INotifyPropertyChange and has a property `ErrorDescription` and `ErrorDescription` has the property `Severity` which is an enum.

Thank you for your help as this is really driving me mad.. displaying the value as text works, but using the value in a DataTrigger does not.

Comment: What if you *do not* explicitly set the Image's DataContext?

Comment: Then the binding to ErrorDescription.Severity does not work (problem with the DataContext)

Comment: But what is the `ValidationResults` property? The current `Result` object?

Comment: That was a typo, I'm sorry.

Comment: I just tested your code, it works for me without setting the DataContext in the DataTemplate.

Comment: Clemens you have saved my day!! It works if I remove the DataContext in the DataTemplate, even though VisualStudio then underlines the Bindings in the DataTrigger with the info "Cannot resolve property "ErrorDescription" in data context of type "MyMainViewModel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not explicitly set the DataContext of the Image in the DataTemplate. Besides that, `Results` would be the wrong property anyway, as it is the whole collection, not an individual element.

Replace

```
<Image DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Results, RelativeSource={...}}">
```

by

```
<Image>
```